# Guarantee a Stack-crash

Tags: malloc

I am trying to make a method (`proc`) that
will guarantee that swap will crash when an uninitialized pointer is
dereferenced.

What I want is that when no memory has been allocated, the program to crash.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (int *px, int *py) {
    int *temp;
    *temp = *px; // Why doesn't this crash?
    *px = *py;
    *py = *temp;
}


int main() {
    int a = 99999;
    int b = -0;
    int c = 0;
    //proc(/* Some args might go here */);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to get a runtime error to occur when you've allocated a variable but didn't initialize it?

Comment: So... why do you want to make something crash?

Comment: @summea the conventional wisdom is that when you have a bug in your code, If you're lucky it will crash.  If you're unlucky it will run.  Crashes draw attention to the bug

Comment: @SamIam Isn't this where debugging is useful?

Comment: Try compiling with debugging off.

Comment: @summea debugging doesn't always catch wrong behavior

Comment: What is `-0`? If you don't know that for integers, `-0` is the same as `0`, please get a programming _book_ NOW. (not a teacher, they violate MANY programming practices)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `temp` is allocated on stack so it may already contains some valid pointer when your program hit the line `*temp = *px;`. In this case the program won't crash even if you did not initialize it. You can debug it using gdb, break on this line and type `p temp` to see the value is stored in it.

However, if you really want the program to crash. Try the following one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (int *px, int *py) {
    int *temp;
    *temp = *px; // Why doesn't this crash?
    *px = *py;
    *py = *temp;
}

void proc(int *px, int *py) {
    int *temp = 0;
    printf("temp = %p\n", temp);
}

int main() {
    int a = 99999;
    int b = -0;
    int c = 0;
    proc(&a, &b);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

The `proc` function should have exactly the same stack layout with `swap`. So it should clear the `temp` pointer before the program invokes `swap`, which could make swap crash on that line.

However, you may need to disable optimization to make it work.